# Error in importing nltk book in python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I have installed python 3.5.2 and nltk 3.0.2. Both are compatible with each other. I have downloaded nltk book as well in python, but when I import all from nltk book, it gives an error.

Secondly, the downloading of all corpora gets stuck at the end. It's unable to be downloaded.

Comment: Can you show us how you import your module and what type of error you get ?

Comment: @LoicM am not able to post a screenshot here here. The command i run is: from import.book import * it says attribute error. can't set attribute.